# What is the difference between float32 vs single and float vs double, if any?

Tags: f#, double, type-alias

I have always considered the types `float32` and `single` to be interchangeable, in that they are type aliases. The same for `float` and `double`. However, they appear to be declared in different assemblies `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators` vs `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators`.

Also, the popup description is slightly different, where F# says on `float32` and `float` that it can take a string and use `Parse()` on it.

However, trying that with `single` and `double` succeeds just fine too:

```
let x = single "12.3"
let y = double "13.4"
```

Is there any difference I should be aware of? I have always used them interchangeably, never really gave it another thought, until I saw the differences in the popups and in signatures:

```
// on hovering, or in FSI, this will have the slightly confusing signature:
// val x: a: double -> float
let x (a: double) = float a
```

Comment: `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(typeof<single>,typeof<float32>);; System.Object.ReferenceEquals(typeof<double>,typeof<float>);;`

Comment: @PetSerAl: if they are referentially equal (your suggestion makes sense and they are equal indeed), how do you explain their differences in the UI and different locations in the assemblies? Or is that just F# playing mind tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of them are just aliases of the corresponding CLR types as you can see in [`prim-types-prelude.fs`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types-prelude.fs#L13-L16).

```ml
    type float32 = System.Single
    type float = System.Double
    type single = System.Single
    type double = System.Double
```

As for the confusing signature consider this:

```
type typA = A;;

type typB = typA;;

let f (x : typA) = (x : typB)
//val f : x:typA -> typB
```

Seems like F# prefers to use the aliases at the places you (or some other definition) used them.

Finally the namespaces you are referring to (`FSharp.Core.Operators`) are referring not to the `float` **type** but the `float` **function** (`float : 'T -> float`). See [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4383).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. You are right, the `ExtraTopLevelOperators` is, of course, for the functions. I wrongly assumed that was the location for the types. Still strange that the functions are located differently and have different tooltips, but act the same (inasmuch as I could tell).